# Need to convert a directory with subdirectorys with images to webp

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Im trying to make my website faster and discovered that converting jpg and png to webp could be a difference so I want to copy all images in my theme directory including the ones in sub directories in a different folder but keep the original directory flow.

After searching on google I found a script on this website and it works and I made the directory flow in a new start folder using mkdir. But my problem is that I have to manualy edit the script and run it in each folder. Because Im not the best with working with bash I have no idea how to edit the converting script to look in all folders and copy them in the new one.

So my question is if there is a way to keep the folder structure as the original but with a different base folder?

```
for file in *.jpg
do
    cwebp -q 100 "$file" -o "/var/www/themes/assets/images/webp/${file%.jpg}.webp"
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ([Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean) code:

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob       # Globs that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s globstar       # ** matches multiple directory levels

root_webp_dir=/var/www/themes/assets/images/webp

for jpg_path in **/*.jpg ; do
    jpg_file=${jpg_path##*/}
    [[ $jpg_path == */* ]] && jpg_dir=${jpg_path%/*} || jpg_dir=.

    webp_dir=${root_webp_dir}/${jpg_dir}
    webp_path=${webp_dir}/${jpg_file%.jpg}.webp

    [[ -d $webp_dir ]] || mkdir -p -- "$webp_dir"
    cwebp -q 100 "$jpg_path" -o "$webp_path"
done
```

Note that the version of `cwebp` that I used for testing (stupidly) doesn't support the `--` convention for terminating command line options.  Otherwise the command would have been (and should be) `cwebp -q 100 -o "$webp_path" -- "$jpg_path"`.  The command in the code above could go wrong if any of the JPEG files has a path that begins with a `-`.  One way to work around the problem and make the code completely safe would be to use `./**/*.jpg` instead of `**/*.jpg` as the glob pattern to find JPEG files.

Answer (score 1):

### cwebp and parallel

We can convert files in parallel using this: `find . | parallel cwebp -quiet {} -o {.}.webp`.  But it assumes you're in the directory and all files are convertable.

```bash
find ./src/img/ -type d | sed 's/src\/img/docs\/www/g' | xargs mkdir
find ./src/img/ | egrep '.jpeg|.jpg|.tiff|.tif|.png' | cut -d/ -f3- | parallel --progress 'cwebp -quiet ./src/img/{} -o ./docs/www/{.}.webp'
```

The first line copies the directory structure of `./src/img/` to `./docs/www/`.
The second converts `jpg`/`tif`/`png` to `webp` in parallel.
*(cut f=`3` because d=`/` is in `./src/img/` 3 times)*

Comment: I recommend the webp params: `cwebp -af -resize 1200 0`